# Connecting to ubuntu mirror repository server

Tags: apt, server, repository

There is a repository server which I have to connect to , but it just accepts 7138 port and I have added the below line to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`  :

```
deb 10.x.x.x:7138/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

But when I run `sudo apt update` It seems apt ignores this line . What should I do now ?

**Update** : when I run change it to :

```
deb http://10.x.x.x:7138/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe
```

I get `badrequest`  error .

**Update2** : As I'm requesting to an apt-cacher server , I changed my proxy.conf with below config :

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://x.x.x.x:3142";
```

And I'm now getting connection failed error .

Comment: Welcome! Are you able to browse that directory from a browser? Have you tried manually downloading an item (even a simple release file) using wget command and the full uri of the object?

Comment: Also: is there any equipment between your client to the server (such as firewall) or something that may alter the http request?

Comment: Thanks , It seems they are using apt catcher , How should I configure it to connect to it ?

Comment: If this helped, I will convert this comment to an answer and you may mark it as accepted so it won't appear as an unanswered question to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on comments solution]

It seems like something might have changed your http request assuming your server is managed properly, as Ubuntu's http requests are always acting the same.

Things like a firewall or other network equipment in the middle of the client and the server might be the cause.

I would first suggest trying to browse the url or try a simple wget command from the terminal to the full request uri of the debian and assure, that is the problem.
If they work, you can actually use them to manually download a debian and install it, tho it is not the most efficient way to do so.

There is no simple solution for such situation, as it depends on your organization's security policy and server management.
You can try other source list configurations as documented by Debian: [SOURCES.LIST(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html), but it really depends on your network and repository configurations.

**Regarding update 2**: a connection fail error means you were unable to reach the server. Unlike "connection refused" or "connection reset", where the http request has reached the server but it won't process the request (wrong port number, wrong request uri and etc).

Things you may try: use the debugging options as documented by Debian: 
[APT.CONF(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html) under the `debugging` section. Or if your organization allows you to: Use wireshark or tcpdump to follow the whole http request session. This might be another cause of a firewall or network configuration related error.

Comment: Thanks , Could you please check my update 2 ?

Comment: Updated, maybe this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment